# Hopcroft–Karp algorithm time complexity

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal, bipartite-matching

In the last 2 paragraphs of the paper about Hopcroft–Karp algorithm to find the maximum cardinality matching in bipartite graph:

> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64823035/04569670.pdf
>
> The execution time of a phase is O(m+n), where m is the number of
>   edges in G, and n is the number of vertices. Hence the execution time
>   of the entire algorithm is O((m+n)s), where s is the cardinality of a
>   maximum matching.
>
> If G has n vertices then m <= n^2 / 4 and s < n / 2 so that the
>   execution time is bounded by O(n^(5/2)).

I don't understand given:

```
m <= n^2 / 4
s <= n / 2
```

why they concluded:

```
O((m+n)s) = O(n^(5/2))
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
O((m+n)s) = O(n^3)
```

Any idea?

Comment: This is explained [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm#Analysis). Remember to research the problem yourself before asking here.

Comment: Thanks. I had referred this Wikipedia before, but was not sure if I should trust Wikipedia or the original algorithm's paper.

Comment: Corollary 5 of the paper says there are only $O(\sqrt{s})$ phases.

Comment: That must be it. I think they forgot to draw the $\sqrt{}$ symbol.

Comment: There does seem to be a space left for it on the fifth-to-last line of the paper before the references (they write `O((m+n) s)` instead of `O((m+n)s)`; compare the sixth-to-last line of the first column of p122). Isn't it good that we don't have to typeset papers that way any more?